# What is the most optimal way to apply a kernel to a large array in F#?

Tags: optimization, f#

I have the following code:

```
// reduce by 25x
let smallOutput = Array2D.init (output.GetLength(0) / 5) (output.GetLength(1) / 5) (fun _ _ -> Int32.MinValue)
let weights =
    array2D [|
        [| 1; 1; 1; 1; 1 |]
        [| 1; 3; 3; 3; 1 |]
        [| 1; 3; 5; 3; 1 |]
        [| 1; 3; 3; 3; 1 |]
        [| 1; 1; 1; 1; 1 |]
    |]
let weightsSum = 45
for y in [0 .. smallOutput.GetLength(0) - 1] do
    for x in [0 .. smallOutput.GetLength(1) - 1] do
        let mutable v = 0
        for i in [0 .. 4] do
            for j in [0 .. 4] do
                v <- v + weights.[j, i] * output.[y * 5 + j, x * 5 + i]

        smallOutput.[y, x] <- v / weightsSum
```

It takes a large matrix (16k x 16k) and reduces it by 25x while applying weights.

I understand I can try to do this in a Parallel.ForEach loop, but I am wondering if there is anything built-in F# that would allow to make this faster in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much you can do to optimize it further, short of doing the summation already when you initialize the `smallOutput` variable; i.e.

```
let smallOutput = Array2D.init (output.GetLength(0) / 5) (output.GetLength(1) / 5) (fun y x -> 
    let mutable v = 0
    for i in [0 .. 4] do
        for j in [0 .. 4] do
            v <- v + weights.[j, i] * output.[y * 5 + j, x * 5 + i]
    v / weightsSum)
```

The thing is, that you need to loop over all entries in the larger array, there's no way getting around that. If you know beforehand the structure of the weighting-matrix, e.g. that it's symmetric in some way, you might be able to utilize that. Thought to be honest, I'm not sure how much of an optimization that would yield.